# draw func doesn't work for button from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In my app I have several `UIButton`s, which I want to be with rounded corners. All of these buttons are placed in Storyboard.

I've created custom class `RoundedButton`, which has simple override of `draw` func.

```
import UIKit

class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    }

}
```

I've added this custom class to every button in Storyboard, but buttons corners are not rounded in simulator.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The `draw` method is not the proper place to set the corner radius. It should be set once in the proper initializer.

Comment: So, where I need to put this code? I want to write it once and not in every VC, where I have UIButtons.

Comment: Did you read my comment? I stated where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead override init

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)

   layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
}
```

EDITED:

if you don't use storyboard, or xib's

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
   super.init(frame: frame)

   layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`draw` method is not the right place to add this piece of code.

You should move it to `awakeFromNib`

Coming to your question, add `self.layer.masksToBounds = true` after setting `cornerRadius`. The rounded corner should then show up.